# how to negate a capture group?

Tags: javascript, regex

Using a javascript regexp, I would like to find strings like `"/foo"` or `"/foo d/"` but not `"/foo /"`; ie, "annotation character", then either word with no terminating annotation, or multiple words, where the termination comes at the end of the phrase (with no space). Complicating the situation, there are three possible annotation symbols: `/`, `\` and `|`.

I've tried something like:

```
/(?:^|\s)([\\\/|])((?:[\w_-]+(?![^\1]+[\w_-]\1))|(?:[\w\s]+[\w](?=\1)))/g
```

That is, start with space, then annotation, then

1. word not followed by (anything but annotation) then letter and annotation... or
2. possibly multiple words, immediately followed by annotation character.

The problem is the `[^\1]`: this doesn't read as "anything but the annotation character" in the angle brackets.

I could repeat the whole phrase three times, one for each annotation character. Any better ideas?

Comment: By the way, `\w` already includes `_`.

Comment: Instead of `[^\1]+`, try `.+?`, to match non-greedily up to the next annotation character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned, `[^\1]` doesn't work - it matches anything that is not the character `1`. In JavaScript, you can negate `\1` by using a lookahead: `(?:(?!\1).)*` . This is not as efficient, but it works.

Your pattern can be written as:

```
([\\\/|])([\w\-]+(?:(?:(?!\1).)*[\w\-]\1)?)
```

[Working example at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/riI3OA/1)

- `\w` already contains underscore.
- Instead of alternation (`a|ab`) I'm using an optional group (`a(?:b)?`) - we always match the first word, with optional further words and tags.
- You may still want to include `(?:^|\s)` at the beginning.